# For while statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question has bothered me for most of the day, just can't figure it out, and I don't really know which keywords to google for.

Let's say I have policies and their date, and I want to know if the policy falls within the first year since its inception or later years. it will have to find the earliest date for each policy, and then return 1 if the future date is within 1 year of the original date.

I know that we need to use for while statements but I don't know how to begin.

Thanks

For example:

```
+--------+-----------+
| Policy |   Date    |
+--------+-----------+
| CC1002 | 5/1/2012  |
| CC1002 | 6/1/2012  |
| CC1002 | 7/1/2012  |
| CC1002 | 8/1/2012  |
| CC1002 | 9/1/2012  |
| CC1002 | 10/1/2012 |
| CC1002 | 11/1/2012 |
| CC1002 | 12/1/2012 |
| CC1002 | 1/1/2013  |
| CC1002 | 2/1/2013  |
| CC1002 | 3/1/2013  |
| CC1002 | 4/1/2013  |
| CC1002 | 5/1/2013  |
| CC1002 | 6/1/2013  |
| CC1002 | 7/1/2013  |
| CC1002 | 8/1/2013  |
| CC1008 | 5/1/2012  |
| CC1008 | 6/1/2013  |
+--------+-----------+
```

Results

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| Policy |   Date    | YearfromInception |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| CC1002 | 5/1/2012  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 6/1/2012  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 7/1/2012  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 8/1/2012  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 9/1/2012  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 10/1/2012 |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 11/1/2012 |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 12/1/2012 |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 1/1/2013  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 2/1/2013  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 3/1/2013  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 4/1/2013  |                 1 |
| CC1002 | 5/1/2013  |                 2 |
| CC1002 | 6/1/2013  |                 2 |
| CC1002 | 7/1/2013  |                 2 |
| CC1002 | 8/1/2013  |                 2 |
| CC1008 | 5/1/2012  |                 1 |
| CC1008 | 6/1/2013  |                 2 |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Solved. This community is great!

Comment: YOu have both sql-server and mysql tagged. It cannot be both as those are both different RDBMS's. Which on are you using?

Comment: sql server. sorry. just thought it would reach bigger community

Comment: No probs. Answers in SQL can differ by RDBMS, so it's important to state which one you are using. MySQL supports different functions and syntax than SQL-Server.

Comment: There is no need to use a loop for this. Just some date math on MIN(Date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you don't use loops -- SQL works on sets.  In this case you want to get the set of all starting dates for policies and then join that back to the original table to get your results.  Like this:

```
SELECT mytable.policy, 
       (datediff(m,sub.inception,mytable.PolicyDate)/12)+1 as yearfrominception
FROM mytable
JOIN (
  SELECT Policy, Min(PolicyDate) as inception
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY Policy
) as sub ON mytable.Policy = sub.Policy
```

Comment: That isn't quite going to work. If the inception is 2014-01-01 and the policy date is 2015-01-01 this would say it has been a year when it has only been a month.

Comment: Take a look at the desired output. Your fine example will have a 1 for 2013-01-01 when it shouldn't actually increase until 2013-05-01 which is one year after the min date. We will have the same issue with datediff.

Comment: @SeanLange there you go.

Comment: Will not always be true. Update the first record to the date '2012-05-31' and results will be incorrect. CC1002 2 2013-05-01 -- showing 2 here, but 1 year had not passed yet

Comment: @sidux - I guess your issue is that counting years by months is not the same as counting them by days?  Possibly, this would depend on the user's particular requirements.  Looks to me like everything is done by the first day of the month so it would be a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without subqueries:

```
CREATE TABLE #a
(
    policy VARCHAR(100),
    pDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002' ,'5/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '6/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '7/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '8/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '9/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '10/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '11/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '12/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '1/1/2013');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '2/1/2013');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '3/1/2013');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '4/1/2013');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '5/1/2013');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '6/1/2013');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '7/1/2013');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1002', '8/1/2013');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1008', '5/1/2012');
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('CC1008', '6/1/2013');

SELECT a.policy ,
       a.pDate ,
       DATEDIFF(DAY,  MIN(a.pDate) OVER (PARTITION BY a.policy), a.pDate)/365+ 1

       FROM #a a
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you mean to return, for each policy/date, the number of years since the policy first existed...

You'll have to figure out the year difference function, date stuff is highly platform dependent (and you seem to want SQL Server and MySQL) and generally need some tweaking.  In my code, it would return 0 years for the first inception row, to which you would add +1 to get your results.

no whiles required.  something like this should work:

```
select Policy
,Date 
,function-datediff-in-years-for-your-db(
  Date, 
(select min(Date) from Policy_table s where s.Policy = Policy_table.Policy)
)
from Policy_table
```

Comment: this will run a sub-query on every row.  very slow

Comment: possibly.  but beware of premature optimization.  also, I have worked on apps that persistently use subqueries to find min/max dates in exactly this kind of context and do so just fine - depends on indexing, really.  as far as the OP goes, this is almost pseudocode for his reqs.

Comment: Writing a query in such a way as to avoid RBAR isn't premature optimization. That isn't to say that this type of technique is destined to be slow.

Comment: It does not depend on indexing -- this is objectively a bad solution.  Make a table with 100k or so rows and try it out.  This solution is the most common mistake starting SQL programmers make.

Comment: your opinion.  Again, I have worked, for years, on large volume apps that track exactly that kind of ID+date compound key combos and work just fine.  with > 100K rows, easily.  If it's slow, optimize it.  Or write it the way you suggest in the first place.  But saying it's a noob error?  Maybe you're assuming too much, eh?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few different ways.  You could set up a table with the MIN(Date) for each record:

```
WITH mindate (Policy, MinDate) as
    (select Policy, min(Date) as MinDate
    from mytable
    group by Policy)
select
    t1.Policy, t1.Date, DATEDIFF(year, t2.MinDate, t1.Date) + 1
from mytable t1 join mindate t2 on
    t1.Policy = t2.Policy
```

I consider this the more universal SQL approach (without using temporary tables), but I believe you can replace the WITH derived table with an analytical function: MIN(Date) over (partition by Policy):

```
select Policy,
DATEDIFF(year, Min(Date) over (partition by Policy), Date) + 1
from mytable
```

That's obviously shorter, but less portable if you move away from SQL Server (although support is growing).  If performance becomes an issue, indexes or temporary tables could speed things up.

Comment: DATEDIFF(year, Min(Date) over (partition by Policy), Date) + 1 will not work.

Comment: Odd.  I tested it; is that a SQL Server version issue?  I don't have access to 2008 any more, and I forget every little thing that's changed.  Or do you mean it is a math issue due to using year where I misinterpreted the original question? I was worried about precision on the roundoff with the 'day' versions for things like leap years.  Oh well, other people beat me to the answer pretty soundly.  Thanks for the feedback.